# Wordpress different label name for shared taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using the same taxonomy for 2 post types:

```
register_taxonomy( my_taxonomy,
        array('portfolio', 'slideshow'), //2 post types share the same taxonomy
        array( 'hierarchical' => true,
                'label' => 'Categories',
                'singular_label' => 'Category',
                'rewrite' => true,
                'query_var' => true,
                'has_archive' => true,
                'show_admin_column' => true,
) );
```

Is it possible to use different labels for each post type? For example,

`'label' => 'Portfolio Categories'` for the portfolio post type

`'label' => 'Slideshow Categories'` for the slideshow post type

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use an if statement to check which post type the user is in and then register the taxonomy depending on that post type. **But i think its a bad idea**, it might have complications later on i would just go for a general label of **'portfolio/slider category'**. It would be look something like this

```
    if ((isset($_GET['post_type']) && $_GET['post_type'] == 'portfolio')){
      register_taxonomy( my_taxonomy,
        array('portfolio', 'slideshow'), //2 post types share the same taxonomy
        array( 'hierarchical' => true,
                'label' => 'Portfolio Categories',
                'singular_label' => 'Category',
                'rewrite' => true,
                'query_var' => true,
                'has_archive' => true,
                'show_admin_column' => true,
) );
    }
```